# Why isn't this readLine() function in C working, returns SIGTRAP?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, readline

```
char * readLine(){
    char c;
    char* line = (char*) malloc(2* sizeof(char));
    if(line == NULL){
        printf("MEM_GRESKA");
        exit(1);
    }
    int sizeOfLine = 2 - 1; //-1 za \0
    int numOfChars = 0;

    scanf("%c",&c);
    while(c != '\n'){
        numOfChars++;
        if(numOfChars >= sizeOfLine){

            line = (char*) realloc(line, 2*sizeOfLine * sizeof(char) );//THIS IS BOLDED WHEN
                                                                       //DEBUGGING
            if(line == NULL){
                printf("MEM_GRESKA");
                exit(1);
            }
            sizeOfLine = 2*sizeOfLine - 1; //-1 for \0
        }
        line[numOfChars - 1] = c;
        scanf("%c",&c);
    }
    line[numOfChars] = '\0';
    line = (char*) realloc(line, (numOfChars + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(line == NULL){
        printf("MEM_GRESKA");
        exit(1);
    }
    return line;
}
```

When I run this code, I sometimes get error **SIGTRAP (trace/breakpoint trap)** and sometimes it works. I am not sure what is the problem, so if anybody can help please reply.
I want to fix this code, but if you have some other options to use it will be okay too, although i would love to know what is wrong with this. Thanks

I tried to fix this thinking the reallocing was the problem, because it points to realloc when debugging, but I cannot fix it. The function serves as line reader, sometimes works sometimes doesnt.

Comment: PSA: You don't need to cast `malloc()` in C.

Comment: You need to realloc *before* you add the null terminator after the loop.

Comment: You don't test the return value from `scanf()` so you've no idea whether you read anything.  A more idiomatic way of writing the loop would be `int c; …; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != EOF) { … }` without any `scanf("we %c", &c)` calls  Note that the type returned by `getchar()` is `int`, not `char`!

Comment: `sizeOfLine = 2*sizeOfLine - 1` If `sizeOfLine`starts at 1, what is the result of this computation?

Comment: Thank you guys very much I dont know how to like these comments since this is my first question but the code working now, thanks for your time very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error resulting in your buffer never getting any bigger.

You start with allocating space for 2 characters:

```
char* line = (char*) malloc(2* sizeof(char));
```

Then you set `sizeOfLine` to 1, attempting to save space for a null byte.

```
int sizeOfLine = 2 - 1;
```

When you later reallocate:

```
line = (char*) realloc(line, 2*sizeOfLine * sizeof(char) );
```

Since `sizeOfLine` is 1, you allocate space for 2 bytes, which is what you had before.  Then you update `sizeOfLine`:

```
sizeOfLine = 2*sizeOfLine - 1;
```

And 2*1-1 is 1, so `sizeOfLine` doesn't change either.

So what you want instead is to have `sizeOfLine` contain the actual size of the buffer:

```
int sizeOfLine = 2;
...
sizeOfLine = 2*sizeOfLine;
```

You don't need to worry about the null byte, since you already expand the buffer any time you write a character to the currently-last allocated byte.

Answer (score 0):

sizeOfLine stays 1 forever, after the second character read, you are storing all further characters in out-of-bounds memory, as your buffer has size 2 all the time.